# Projective special linear groups are co-hopfian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices, field-theory, simple-groups

Is it known if $PSL(2,\, F)$, with $F$ a field of prime $p$ characteristic (maybe with all proper subfields of finite order), is co-hopfian?
I've searched everywhere but found nothing.

**Definition**

A group $G$ is called co-hopfian if $G$ has no proper subgroups isomorphic to $G$.

Comment: It will depend on $F$. For example, if $F$ is finite then $\operatorname{PSL}(2,F)$ is obviously co-hopfian, since it's finite. But if $F$ contains a proper subfield $F'$ isomorphic to $F$ then $\operatorname{PSL}(2,F')<\operatorname{PSL}(2,F)$, so it's not co-hopfian.

Comment: Dear @JeremyRickard : Please consider moving that to a solution.

Comment: @rschwieb I'm just waiting a bit to see if the OP wants to clarify what kinds of field he's interested in.

Comment: Dear @JeremyRickard : That's fine, but if nothing happens, please eventually make that a solution :)

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thanks for waiting (and thanks for the answer). If I've well understood it seems that $Z_p[x^2]<Z_p[x]$ will be fine, in general?

May I now add the condition of having all proper subfields of finite order? Sorry about the trick. Do you maybe know what happen in this case? (Otherwise I'll accept just your first answer, and maybe I will open another question.)

Comment: Of course I meant the fields of fractions of $Z_p[x]$ and $Z_p[x^2]$.

Comment: @W4cc0 I suspect $\operatorname{PSL}(2,F)$ is co-hopfian when $F$ is any algebraic extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$, and I think I have the beginnings of a strategy to prove it. I'll try to work out the details when I have some time, but in the meantime I've posted my comment on the easy cases as an answer.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thanks! I am really interested in this result! :) Also if you do not have the time to work out the details you may tell me and I'll try to figure out the details by myself; I will appreciate anyhow. In middletime, have I to accept the answer in this form?

Comment: @W4cc0 I've edited my answer with what I think is a proof that $\operatorname{PSL}(2,F)$ is co-hopfian if $F$ is algebraic. I suspect the argument can be simplified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the field $F$. For example, if $F$ is finite then $\operatorname{PSL}(2,F)$ is certainly co-hopfian, since it's finite. But if $F$ contains a proper subfield $F'$ isomorphic to $F$ then $\operatorname{PSL}(2,F')<\operatorname{PSL}(2,F)$, so it's not co-hopfian: for example, if $\mathbb{F}_p(x)$ is the field of rational functions, $\operatorname{PSL}\left(2,\mathbb{F}_p(x^2)\right)$ is a proper subgroup of $G=\operatorname{PSL}\left(2,\mathbb{F}_p(x)\right)$ that is isomorphic to $G$.

**EDIT:** In comments, the OP asked about fields such that all proper subfields are finite. I think that, more generally, if $F$ is algebraic then $\operatorname{PSL}(2,F)$ is co-hopfian. Here's at least the outline of a proof (I've not tried very hard to simplify it, but I suspect it can be simplified):

$F$ can be expressed as the union of a chain
$$F_1\leq F_2\leq \dots$$
of finite fields, where $F_i=\mathbb{F}_{p^{d_i}}$ (so $d_i$ divides $d_{i+1}$). A few of the facts I claim later on are false for some very small fields, but we can choose $F_1$ large enough that we avoid the counterexamples.

Suppose $\alpha:\operatorname{PSL}(2,F)\to\operatorname{PSL}(2,F)$ is an injective group homomorphism. We need to show that $\alpha$ is surjective.

Let $\alpha_i:\operatorname{PSL}(2,F_i)\to\operatorname{PGL}(2,\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)$ be the composition of inclusion maps
$$\operatorname{PSL}(2,F_i)\to\operatorname{PSL}(2,F)\stackrel{\alpha}{\to}\operatorname{PSL}(2,F)\to\operatorname{PGL}(2,\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p).$$

If $p>2$, then by taking the pullback with the natural surjection $\operatorname{GL}(2,\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)\to\operatorname{PGL}(2,\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)$, we get an inclusion of a double cover of each $\operatorname{PSL}(2,F_i)$ into $\operatorname{GL}(2,\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)$. Since $\operatorname{PSL}(2,F_i)$ has no non-trivial $2$-dimensional representations over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$, this must be a non-trivial double cover. But the only such double cover is $\operatorname{SL}(2,F_i)$, so we get a compatible family of inclusions
$$\beta_i:\operatorname{SL}(2,F_i)\to \operatorname{GL}(2,\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p),$$
and so an inclusion
$$\beta:\operatorname{SL}(2,F)\to \operatorname{SL}(2,F),$$
that we need to show is surjective. (If $p=2$, then just take $\beta=\alpha$, $\beta_i=\alpha_i$.)

The only non-trivial $2$-dimensional representations of $\operatorname{SL}(2,F_i)$ are equivalent to Frobenius twists of the natural representation, so (letting $\varphi$ be the Frobenius map, raising all entries of matrices to the $p$th power) there are elements $g_i\in\operatorname{GL}(2,\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)$ and non-negative integers $r_i$ such that
$$\beta_i=c_i\circ\varphi^{r_i},$$
where $c_i$ is conjugation by $g_i$.

Since the resriction of $\beta_{i+1}$ to $\operatorname{SL}(2,F_i)$ is equal to $\beta_i$, we must have $r_{i+1}\equiv r_i\pmod{d_i}$ and $g_{i+1}^{-1}g_i$ must be in the centralizer of $\operatorname{SL}(2,F_i)$ in $\operatorname{GL}(2,\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)$. But this centralizer is the centre of $\operatorname{GL}(2,\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)$, so without loss of generality we can take $g=g_1=g_2=\dots$.

But then the $\operatorname{im}(\beta)\leq\operatorname{SL}(2,F)$ is conjugate in $\operatorname{GL}(2,\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)$, by $g$, to 
$$\operatorname{SL}(2,F)=\bigcup_i\operatorname{SL}(2,F_i).$$

Since $\operatorname{GL}(2,\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)$ is the union of finite subgroups, $g$ has finite order, and so $\operatorname{im}(\beta)=\operatorname{SL}(2,F)$.

Comment: I just come back from a week of holidays. In the nexts few days I will read all and make you know about anything. Thanks!